# Storybook Vue3 initial page

Tags: vuejs3, storybook

So I started working on our Storybook configuration and components last Monday, read through the documentation and watched some videos on their YT channel and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I really like the Audi React Storybook configuration (https://react.ui.audi/) and I was wondering how they managed to have an intro page as the first thing you see when you run Storybook. They have a page called Introduction and I like to do the same.

However, the index.stories.js page doesnt do anything, I can see it in the sidebar but it is not opened as the default page. Instead it opens my first component.

I have these packages installed:

```
"@storybook/addon-docs": "^7.6.7",
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.6.7",
"@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.6.7",
"@storybook/addon-links": "^7.6.7",
"@storybook/blocks": "^7.6.7",
"@storybook/test": "^7.6.7",
"@storybook/vue3": "^7.6.7",
"@storybook/vue3-vite": "^7.6.7",
```

I don't know if these packages are all correct, as I am just starting out with Storybook. I managed to put all our components in there.

I made a "index.stories.js" file in the src/stories dir and it contains:

```
// src/stories/index.stories.js

import Welcome from '@/stories/Welcome.vue';

export default {
  components: { Welcome },
  title: 'Welcome',
};

export const Introduction = () => ({
  template: '<Welcome />',
});
```

The Welcome component looks like this:

```
<!-- src/stories/Welcome.vue -->

<template>
  <div>Welcome to Storybook with Vue 3</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Welcome'
};

</script>
```

My main.js file (located in .storybook) looks like this:

```
/** @type { import('@storybook/vue3-vite').StorybookConfig } */

const config = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|mdx)',
    './stories/index.stories.js',
    './stories/documentation.stories.js',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    "@storybook/addon-docs"
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/vue3-vite',
    options: {},
  },
}
export default config
```

And my preview.js file looks like this:

```
    // import {app} from '@storybook/vue3';
// import BootstrapIcon from '@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons';
// app.component('BootstrapIcon', BootstrapIcon);

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
import { setup } from "@storybook/vue3";
import CustomLogo from '../src/assets/img/logo-bip.png'; // Import your custom logo component


setup((app) => {
  app.component("CustomLogo", CustomLogo);
});

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    expanded: true,
    hideNoControlsWarning: true,
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
// Use the brand parameter to customize the Storybook header
  // You can provide a name, title, and/or a logo
  // Logo should be an object with a dark and light mode
  // Example:
  brand: {
    name: 'Your Storybook',
    title: 'Your Storybook Title',
    logo: {
      dark: 'path/to/your/logo-dark.png',
      light: 'path/to/your/logo-light.png',
    },
  },
};
```

So tldr; how can I make a page the first page that loads when one visits the localhost:6006 Storybook?